# Different behavior of PYTHONPATH on Windows and Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, python

I am trying to set up the same Python github project on Windows and Linux.
On Windows, I have

```
echo %PYTHONPATH%
c:\project_foo
```

On Linux I have

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
:/home/vagrant/project_foo
```

Inside the folder `project_foo`, there is another folder `project_foo` which contains the source code.

On Windows, these imports work fine:

```
import project_foo.module_1
import project_foo.module_2
```

On Linux, it does not work. It gives me the error:

```
>>> import project_foo.module_1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named project_foo.module_1
```

However, if I add `/home/vagrant/` to my PYTHONPATH, the above works on Linux. Alternatively, on Linux this works too:

```
import module_1
```

Why is this? Why are Windows and Linux behaving differently? Which is the behavior intended by python?

Comment: "Why is this?" - How a system path variable works on Linux and Windows is different. "Why are Windows and Linux behaving differently?" - They are not the same operating system.  "Which is the behavior intended by python?" - Both are intended  and correct.

Comment: It seems strange to me that on Linux I have to add the directory one level "lower" than on Windows because isn't it a Python thing to interpret PYTHONPATH?

Comment: As I point out Windows and Linux are not identical.  You are not going to be able to have an identical project environment between them.